# HTML/JavaScript/CSS/PHP code to update width % to height in pixels

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I don't know which will be needed if not all but here's my problem.

I want to make 5 div squares spanding across the page. Obviously I would make the width 20% for each but if I change the height to 20% then it won't be a square. I need a command that will find out how many pixels the width is then change the height to that number. I need it to update live. It's for an article page on my website.

Also I'm a newbie at Javascript & PHP but I'm fairly good at HTML & CSS

If you have an easier way to do this please do tell :)

Thanks for helping out a junior coder!

Answer (score 1):

```
width = jQuery('#container div').width();
jQuery('div').css('height', width);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b8aw4jbv/1/

Comment: Not entirely correct. You set the height of all div's to the height of the first div.

Comment: You shouldn't use javascript for that. Plus it doesn't handle window resize.

Answer (score 1):

it can be done by css only using `padding-bottom`:

```css
.square{
  width:20%;
  padding-bottom:20%;
  background-color:green;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
.square .content{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

its responsive, and no need to run js or load jQuery

EDIT: `padding` with percentage value calculate its value from parent's **width** so `padding-bottom` take 20% of parent width. `.content` need `position:absolute` and be stretched to whole div to ignore this padding and show content in it on proper place

Comment: Explanation why it works should be added, which is because padding and margin is calculated according to element width and absolute positioning allows to fill entire block without knowing size of it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with javascript jquery like:

```
$('div').each({
    $(this).height($(this).width());
});
```

What does this code:
- it loops over the divs in your page
- it sets the height of the div to the width of the div (in pixels)

Comment: I don't know jquery but I'm willing to learn how to implement it. Could you link me to valuable tutorials or pfd's?? I'm going to copy that code and implement it when I understand how it works properly :) But thankyou

Comment: Well, you added the tag jquery to your question - so you should know the basics. Use http://jquery.com to learn the basics!

Answer (score 0):

So, basically, what you want to do is having divs with an aspect ratio of 1:1.

It is possible to accomplish that with only CSS.
Here's how:
http://codepen.io/DisColow/pen/pJKZOb

I simply set all my squares to have a width and to be floating left.
Then, I add a :before pseudo element for each of those squares which has the following CSS rule:

```
padding-bottom: 100%;
```

When you specify a percentage to a padding-bottom, it's relative to the parent container width. Therefore, I simple tell my square to be as tall as it is wide.

Hope it helped.

You then can write your content inside the square-inner div.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "div" ).each(function() {
    var divWidth = $(this).width();  // Get Width
    $(this).height(divWidth);        // Set height
});
```

Comment: Though you shouldn't use javascript for such a thing (because you can do it with pure css), you should wrap all your code inside a jQuery(window).resize(/* your code here */); because the user will change the window size.